# How can I save frames from an IP camera to disk on demand?

Tags: video, webcam

I have an IP camera that is running correctly. I can open `http:its.address.com/videostream.cgi` in my browser and view the video successfully.  Now I would like to create a program or script that saves X seconds worth of video whenever I run it.

I thought maybe VLC would do this, but I get `No suitable decoder module for fourcc 'MJPG'. VLC probably does not support this sound or video format`.  I reinstalled VLC with apt-get and get the same result.

1. What is the best tool for the job of recording frames on
   demand?
2. If it is VLC, how do I get MJPG support?

*(Ubuntu 12.04)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether this is the *best* tool, but did you have look at [Zoneminder](http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_Server_12.04_64-bit_with_Zoneminder_1.25.0_the_easy_way)?

Comment: This doesn't work exactly like I wanted, but it will meet our needs.